# How to put one big line of data (it has separators) into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling to get some data into a pandas dataframe (newbie). The data (actually from an URL) is one big line with a comma as columndelimiter and a semicolon as rowdelimiter. Can someone help me with the code? This is what I see in the browser:

```
20210301,12:25,987,0.359,NaN,408,0.148,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:30,1022,0.372,NaN,420,0.153,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:35,1057,0.384,NaN,420,0.153,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:40,1089,0.396,NaN,384,0.140,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:45,1147,0.417,NaN,696,0.253,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:50,1200,0.436,NaN,636,0.231,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:55,1259,0.458,NaN,708,0.257,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:00,1332,0.484,NaN,876,0.319,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:05,1401,0.509,NaN,828,0.301,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:10,1449,0.527,NaN,576,0.209,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:15,1487,0.541,NaN,456,0.166,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:20,1534,0.558,NaN,564,0.205,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:25,1583,0.576,NaN,588,0.214,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:30,1643,0.597,NaN,720,0.262,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:35,1701,0.619,NaN,696,0.253,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:40,1756,0.639,NaN,660,0.240,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:45,1827,0.664,NaN,852,0.310,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:50,1967,0.715,NaN,1680,0.611,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:55,2099,0.763,NaN,1584,0.576,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,14:00,2248,0.817,NaN,1788,0.650,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,14:05,2388,0.868,NaN,1680,0.611,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib as ul

link = "https://xxxxxxxxx"
f = ul.request.urlopen(link)
mydata = f.read()
print(mydata)
```

Output:

```
b'20210301,12:25,987,0.359,NaN,408,0.148,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:30,1022,0.372,NaN,420,0.153,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:35,1057,0.384,NaN,420,0.153,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:40,1089,0.396,NaN,384,0.140,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301'
```

I have to add the headers myself also. I don't know how to get pandas to take it in like this:

```
| Date     | Time  | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4
| -------- | ----- | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
| 20210301 | 12:25 | 987    | 0.359  | NaN    | ...
| 20210301 | 12:30 | 1022   | 0.372  | NaN    | ...
| ...      | ...   | ...    | ...    | ...    | ...
```

I don't know which pandas method to use and how. Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic word your are after is [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) (just follow the link for the doc).

The options for your use case are not trivial and the only foolproof way is to check the doc page, but this is what you want:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(mydata), lineterminator=';', sep=',',
                 header=None, names=['Date', 'Time', 'Value1', 'Value2',
                                     'Value3', 'Value4'],
                 usecols=range(6))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), since your data is almost in CSV (comma separated value) format. Just replace `;` with `\n` (which indicates a new line).

```py
import pandas as pd
import urllib as ul
from io import BytesIO

link = "https://xxxxxxxxx"
f = ul.request.urlopen(link)
mydata = f.read()
mydata_csv = mydata.replace(b";", b"\n")

df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(mydata_csv))
```

Comment: Pandas read_csv has an option for an arbitrary line terminator...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can read the contents as a string object and then use `string.replace(";", "\n")` which will make the data an appropriate csv-data and then you can read it and use it like a normal csv file using `pd.read_csv()`.

This would help I guess.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = "20210301,12:25,987,0.359,NaN,408,0.148,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:30,1022,0.372,NaN,420,0.153,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:35,1057,0.384,NaN,420,0.153,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:40,1089,0.396,NaN,384,0.140,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:45,1147,0.417,NaN,696,0.253,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:50,1200,0.436,NaN,636,0.231,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,12:55,1259,0.458,NaN,708,0.257,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:00,1332,0.484,NaN,876,0.319,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:05,1401,0.509,NaN,828,0.301,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:10,1449,0.527,NaN,576,0.209,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:15,1487,0.541,NaN,456,0.166,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:20,1534,0.558,NaN,564,0.205,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:25,1583,0.576,NaN,588,0.214,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:30,1643,0.597,NaN,720,0.262,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:35,1701,0.619,NaN,696,0.253,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:40,1756,0.639,NaN,660,0.240,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:45,1827,0.664,NaN,852,0.310,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:50,1967,0.715,NaN,1680,0.611,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,13:55,2099,0.763,NaN,1584,0.576,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,14:00,2248,0.817,NaN,1788,0.650,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;20210301,14:05,2388,0.868,NaN,1680,0.611,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN"

data = data.replace(";", "\n")

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), names=["Date", "Time", "Value1", "Value2"], header=None)

df.head()
```